# Makefile : why put .o instead of .c in dependencies?

Tags: makefile

In this tutorial : http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

I don't understand why he uses .c dependencies in  `Makefile1` and .o in  `Makefile2`. Can you put .o and .c regardless in gcc ? What's the advantage of using .o ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess Beta has cleared most of your doubt.

I want to add some more basic points as to `What's the advantage of using .o?`

when building projects there are two steps for the building final binary

1. Compile - The compiler syntax checking and other compilation conditions. `.o` files will  be generated as the output at this stage
2. Linking - Function calls will be mapped. All the `.o` created in the above step will be linked to produce the final binary

But why to use two steps?

For a vey small project it wont matter much but when the project grows larger then its really hard to put all the files under single gcc line. and even harder to map the dependency files etc.

Lets rewrite the `Makefile2` with [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit) for compiling `.c`

```
hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
     $(CC) -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o

#Below rules will be provided by make implicit rules
hellomake.o: hellomake.c
     $(CC) -c hellomake.c
hellofunc.o: hellofunc.c
     $(CC) -c hellofunc.c
```

Now suppose you change the file `hellofunc.c` then only `hellofunc.o` will be recompiled and final linking will happen in stead of compiling everything again unlike in `Makefile1`.
It may seem whats the big difference but when you make changes into a single file of a big project then the time complexity will be huge.

Comment: Thank you for you answer I didn't know about the implicit rules that were automatically called when using the .o dependencies, now things are much clearer for me. There is still one thing I don't understand : if you keep `hellomake: hellomake.c hellofunc.c`, wouldn't the compilator act simimlarly and compile only the modified sources ?

Comment: No it won't. If you mention `.o` in dependency then it will check for any rules if its there in current makefile. If no rule is provided explicitly then make will try to use the implicit rules

Comment: Check this https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit

Answer (score 2):

1) It's right there in the tutorial: *"By putting the object files--hellomake.o and hellofunc.o--in the dependency list and in the rule, make knows it must first compile the .c versions individually, and then build the executable hellomake."* Not strictly correct, but you can see what the author meant.

2) You can do it either way, but you should be aware of what these two methods actually do. Also, compare:

```
gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.

gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o
```

The `-I.` isn't needed in the second usage; the compiler can't use it and will ignore it. (Yes, I know the command in the tutorial uses it-- the author is wrong.)

3) The biggest advantage that I know of is the ability to keep the object files (`foo.o`) so as to avoid unnecessary recompilation later; there may be others.

Comment: Yes I've read the line you quoted but I still don't understand because it would mean that with `gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I` "make doesn't know it must first compile the .c version individually and then build the executable hellomake". It doesn't make much sense to me but maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: @Wicelo: Don't confuse what *Make* does, with what *the compiler* does. Make doesn't know anything about compiling, it simply executes the commands in its rules-- some of which are commands that invoke the compiler.